# How to make sure columns in QTableView are resized to the maximum

Tags: qt, qtableview

I'm not sure how to ask this, so, feel free to ask for more information.

It seems that `tableView->resizeColumnsToContents()` will only resize all the columns based on data in current view. Which means that if I have more data below (which is longer in terms of counts of words), those words will be wrapped down (if the `wordWrap` property is set to true).

The weird thing is, if I scroll down to the bottom and refresh the data, `tableView` will resize those columns correctly. It seems as if `tableView` didn't know there are longer text below.

So, my question is, how can I make sure those columns are resized to the max based on all of the data?

My codes

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel;
model->setTable("item");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();    
tableResult->setModel(model);    
tableResult->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);    
tableResult->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
tableResult->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);    
tableResult->resizeColumnsToContents();
tableResult->resizeRowsToContents();
```

**Update 1**

I've tried `tableResult->scrollToBottom()` and it will only resize based on items at the bottom. So, if there are longer words in the middle, those words will get wrapped.

**Update 2**

If anyone would like to understand what I'm talking about, just <strike>[download](http://www.pikopong.com/tmp/cekpo.zip)</strike> this example. You'll see that clicking the PushButton will generate a data that's not resized correctly.

**Update 3**

Possibly a bug: [https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-9352](http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-9352)

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. only the rows that are visible resize. Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: Since Qt 5.2 you can call setResizeContentsPrecision(n) on the QHeaderView, where n is the number of rows it considers when resizing (or -1 for all rows). https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setResizeContentsPrecision

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround for this issue, you just need to hide the table before calling `resizeColumnsToContents()`.

For an example:

```
tableResult->setVisible(false);
tableResult->resizeColumnsToContents();
tableResult->setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Strangely, `table.resizeColumnsToContents()` works without hiding/showing the table with PyQt5

Comment: In Qt 5.6 also `table.resizeColumnsToContents()` works without hiding/showing the table

Comment: Here in qt5.6, still need this tableResult->setVisible(false); the hiding/showing to let it work, in my scenario we hide or show columns in different cases, if not doing hide/show, this resize not work.

Answer (score 6):

I think that is because QSqlTableModel loads data on demand and the view calculates the column widths based only on data that is available. If you don't need your columns to be user-resizable, you can try this:

```
tableResult->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

Comment: It's not working. The column is still not resizing correctly. I put the code at the end of the function. I've also tried QList<QStringList> as the source of the data with QStandardItemModel as the model.

Answer (score 5):

I used the same workaround as described by amree, which worked great for the column widths, but `tableView->resizeRowsToContents()` wasn't working correctly if any offscreen columns had multiline cells that should have caused a row's height to increase.

I looked into the Qt source and it appears that some of the calculations depend on the viewport geometry. This seems to make everything work correctly for both columns and rows:

```
#include <limits>

tableView->setVisible(false);
QRect vporig = tableView->viewport()->geometry();
QRect vpnew = vporig;
vpnew.setWidth(std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
tableView->viewport()->setGeometry(vpnew);
tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
tableView->resizeRowsToContents();
tableView->viewport()->setGeometry(vporig);
tableView.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: amree's answer helped me, but I ran into a problem with auto-sizing row heights at the same time and thought it would be helpful to future readers to post my solution to that closely-related problem. A little more than "essentially nothing", I'd say.